# Running `react-scripts build` fails, but there is no output about what went wrong

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I have an NPM script for building react application written like this `"build": "react-scripts build"`. When I run `npm run build` the following (incomplete) directory structure is created:

```
build
|-- images
|-- manifest.json
```

After some time the command completes but the output is some minimized code followed by many lines of whitespace and a single red `^`.

I tried increasing heap memory size with `--max_old_space_size=8192` but the result is the same. How do I even debug this?

I use npm 9.3.1, node v18.14.1 and react scripts 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by LightningChart JS library, particularly "@arction/lcjs" package. Merely by including import statement such as `import { emptyFill } from @arction/lcjs` caused the build to fail. Updating to React 18 solved the problem.